# How to measure ALL independent variables in ALL AND DIFFERENT combinations influence the dependent variable

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, statistics, data-analysis

[Different combinations for independent variables: what I need in the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18gmS.png)

EDIT: How to measure ALL independent variables in ALL and DIFFERENT combinations influence the dependent variable (PLEASE see the above image for what I need to do)

I'm given a large dataset with 6 independent variables and 1 dependent variable.

My goal is to measure how all of the 6 independent variables (all of them in different combinations) influence the dependent variable (like what I put in the image above).

ANOVA / Multiple linear regression analysis / OLS regression doesn't work because it only has 1 independent variable VS. 1 dependent variable.

MNOVA / Turkey HSD post-hoc test doesn't work because it measures 2 independent variables VS. 1 dependent variable.

What can I do to complete this analysis? Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: In general this is a very difficult question to answer, so I think you should expect to be able to make progress on it and answer it to some extent, but don't expect to get to a complete answer. That said, this is off topic for this forum; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.